# A few questions on command "fsutil behavior query disabledeletenotify"

Tags: windows-10, ssd, fsutil

This command outputs the following text:

```
NTFS DisableDeleteNotify = 0
ReFS DisableDeleteNotify = 0
```

I have two SSD drives. Both are on NTFS.

Question 1. How to understand which line is responsible for which SSD drive?

Question 2. Why does the second line start with ReFS? Both disks are in NTFS.

Comment: Behavior: “Control file system behavior”. These are fs-specific settings. They are (mostly) not volume- or even drive-specific.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is not drive/disk specific, it's global and hence affects every drive/disk in use.

You can only set a different behavior per filesystem format (NTFS vs ReFS).

To determine which feature can be set for different types of disks or filesystems, check the help output of the `set` parameter.
If there's an additional filter available (like "Volume Path"), it can be set independently per disk/drive.

```
fsutil behavior set /?
Usage: fsutil behavior set <option> <value>

<option>                         <values>
  allowExtChar                     <0|1>
  bugcheckOnCorrupt                <0|1>
  defaultNtfsTier                  <1-2>
  disable8dot3                     <0-3> | [<Volume Path> <0|1>]
  disableCompression               <0|1>
  disableCompressionLimit          <0|1>
  disableDeleteNotify              [NTFS|ReFS] <0|1>
  disableEncryption                <0|1>
  disableFileMetadataOptimization  <0-3>
  disableLastAccess                <0-3> | <0|1>
  disableSpotCorruptionHandling    <0-15>
  disableTxF                       [<Volume Path> <0|1>]
  disableWriteAutoTiering          [<Volume Path> <0|1>]
  enableNonpagedNtfs               <0|1>
  enableReallocateAllDataWrites    [<Volume Path> <0|1>]
  encryptPagingFile                <0|1>
  memoryUsage                      <1|2>
  mftZone                          <1-100> (this value multiplied by 200 MB)
  parallelFlushOpenThreshold       <100-1,000,000>
  parallelFlushThreads             <0-32>
  quotaNotify                      <1-4,294,967,295> seconds
  symlinkEvaluation                [<L2L>|<L2R>|<R2L>|<R2R>:<0|1>] [...]

Some of these options require a reboot to take effect.

Please use "fsutil 8dot3name set /?" for more information on modifying the
shortname behavior of the volume or system.

For DisableDeleteNotify if neither "NTFS" nor "ReFS" is specified, "NTFS" is assumed.

MftZone is a reserved region of the disk used to make the MFT contiguous.  The
200 MB multiplier is only applicable for volumes > 1.5 GB.  Below this threshold
the multiplier is scaled based on volume size.

Sample SymlinkEvaluation command:
  "fsutil behavior set symlinkEvaluation L2L:1 L2R:0"
        - Will enable local to local symbolic links and disable local to
          remote symbolic links. It will not change the state of remote to
          remote links or remote to local links.
        - This operation takes effect immediately (no reboot required)
```

**MSFT Docs:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-behavior

To set an option for a specific disk, you would need the GUID.
One option to get the GUID is to use the following PS-Command.

```
PS> get-disk | select FriendlyName, GUID

FriendlyName                   GUID
------------                   ----
WDC WD20EZRX-00DC0B0           {b3ae8925-0dbd-44cf-8ae2-953bbf6d2901}
WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0           {7d88cdd2-2c9b-48ff-b87b-255fbeb3b1bd}
Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB   {48cfe2d8-6f0b-49bb-87d7-25703f38fcf6}
Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB {8c370453-4b36-4696-a424-0dbc0eaa6776}
```

Then you can set or query the current setting (prefix the GUID with `volume`)

```
PS> fsutil behavior query disable8dot3 "Volume{8c370453-4b36-4696-a424-0dbc0eaa6776}"
The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is ENABLED)
The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default)

Based on the above settings, 8dot3 name creation is ENABLED on "Volume{8c370453-4b36-4696-a424-0dbc0eaa6776}"
```